# ICESCRUM Accesing error

Tags: localhost

I am unable to access icescrum on other machines connected in a lan with same url.
I am getting following error:

Your server url: http://localhost:8080/icescrum must be changed in order to let network users use your iceScrum server.

Answer (score 0):

Icescrum use Tomcat as web server and Tomcat uses port 8080 by default. So you have to provide the port number in the URL to see anything.
 If it is running http://yourcomputerIP:8080/app should do the trick.

**Useful resources**
Tomcat documentation: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/index.html

[Beginning & Intermediate Servlet & JSP Tutorials](http://courses.coreservlets.com/Course-Materials/csajsp2.html)

[Tomcat for beginning Web developers](https://www6.software.ibm.com/developerworks/education/j-tomcat/j-tomcat-a4.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

you typed wrong address (url) which is localhost. if you want to run     icescrum in other machine do the following: in the machine where you     installed icescrum (called also localhost in this case) go to       terminal and type : `ip a s |grep inet` (linux) or `ipconfig` in       windows, than copy the ip adrdess of this machine (suppose it is       X.X.X.). now go to other machines in your lan and type       http://X.X.X.X:8080/icescrum. so in the end you have to type the ip      address of the machine where icescrum is installed followed by port      8080/icescrum

---